# How to conditionally replace numbers using vim

Tags: vim, replace, numbers, find

I can see a lot of discussion on how to replace strings conditionally using `:%s`. But I want to do exactly this in my file that has a huge bunch of numbers in a CSV format:

1. Find numbers `< -100`
2. Replace them by `-98`

How can I do this in VIM or any other editor/script language?

Comment: Isn't it working if you use `:%s` just like you use it with string/text?

Comment: could you please elaborate? the trouble here is - this is almost like this Excel formula: if(X<-100,-98,X) - is there any way to implement it in VIM?

Comment: Oh sorry, misunderstood. I think, you won't be able to do that kind of formula thing. After all, vim is just a text editor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible using the `submatch()` function like this:

```
:%s/-[0-9]\+/\=submatch(0) < -100 ? -98 : submatch(0)/g
```

Now every number smaller than -100 will be replaced by -98 and the rest just stays the same. Note that this regex will only match negative numbers.

Comment: A final `/g` flag may be required for matching _"every numbers"_.

Comment: True! Thanks for noticing!

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is super helpful!

Comment: @BadriNarayananGopalakrishnan awesome that it helpend you out! Feel free to accept the answer if it is what you where looking for :)

Comment: Wow. Such a hidden gem. Thanks for your info about this submatch.

Comment: @SanderVanhove Thanks a lot again -  I'm not so frequent here - so I missed your follow up . Sorry for the delay, but indeed this is exactly what I was looking for. Accepted the answer.